# Building a user system with PHP (Code Igniter) and MongoDB

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, authentication, database

I want to switch from a MySQL database to a Mongo database. Especially the syntax seems more user-friendly, but that's not important right now.

I want to write a user authentication login system which basically verifies the email & password sent by the user agains the database (and acts accordingly). As I'm not extremely familiar with MongoDB and its user system, I was wondering: Should I treat users as 'Documents in a Collection' with `db.insert()` or should I  create actual database users with `db.createUser()` call?

The first option seems more SQL-like (in a MySQL database, I would create a table called `users` with according columns), whereas the second option reminds me of users that have access to phpMyAdmin in order to monitor the database, but not users that actually use the application I am building.

I tried searching information on login systems with MongoDB but I couldn't really find anything that confirms or denies my intuitions.

Answer (score 0):

i think SQL is best choice to create login systems, but if you need to create login system using MongoDB you can create collection called user and field called username and password
may this can help you [enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.sqltomongo.php)

Comment: Thanks! The link is very useful.